# Detecting if a content fits in in a div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to detect if the content fits in a div that has width and height fixed? For example, would I be able to do something like

```
theString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
if (document.getElementById("box").wouldOverflowWithContent(theString)){
    /*Do stuff*/
}
```

I can't just count how many letters would go in the box because the box's size is dependent on the screen size ([this webpage](http://cosmiccalender.web44.net)). Thanks in advance. By the way, I can use jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if `scrollHeight` is greater than `offsetHeight`:

```
function check_overflow(elt) {
    return elt.scrollHeight > elt.offsetHeight;
}
```

Comment: Would you tell me why this (http://jsbin.com/celizicoco/1/edit) is not working? I'm confused.

Comment: Because it is not overflowing vertically, which is what the function checks for. If you want to check for overflowing horizontally, you'll need to to check that `scrollWidth` is greater than `offsetWidth`.